# ChoosePixelFormat crashes, even when LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress is used

Tags: opengl, crash, wgl

On a single computer my app is crashing during OpenGL initialization, particularlu call to ChoosePixelFormat. I found this:

[wglCreateContext in C# failing but not in managed C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199016/wglcreatecontext-in-c-sharp-failing-but-not-in-managed-c/206933#206933)

Call to a GL function at the beginning of the app (gefore any DC function) didn't help at all. So I loaded the opengl32.dll manually and obtained wglChoosePixelFormat pointer. On computers, where it worked, it still works, but it didn't help the issue on that particular computer at all.

Any ideas?
*For the record, that computer is on Win7 64. I don't have access to it, but I'll ask the person to tell me, which GPU it has.
Ok, the computer is ACER Aspire 7740 with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a malfunctioning driver, ATI as usual... After installing newest compatible Catalyst, it starts working correctly.